# Is there a better approach at rewriting this code snippet?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Consider the following:

```
if ((a || b) && (c || d))
{
    if (a && c) {...}
    else if (b && d) {...}
    else {...}
}
else {...}
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are expressions that result in a `bool`.

As is clear from the code, few of these expressions are being recalculated. Is there a better approach in terms of a) clarity? b) Efficiency?

Comment: this question would be more fit to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What are you worried about? Clarity or efficiency?

Comment: @TartanLlama Clarity is the priority. But would also love to know the efficiency aspect

Comment: For efficiency, I doubt you'll see any difference in the compiled code. For clarity, I was going to suggest the answer which @TimBiegeleisen posted. It could depend on what those expressions are though.

Answer (score 6):

Surprise: I don't think you really need the outer `if` statement.  Appreciate that using the laws of logic the outer `if` can be rewritten from:

```
if ((a || b) && (c || d))
```

to

```
if ( ((a && c) || (a && d)) || ((b && c) || (b && d)) )
```

In other words, if `(a && c)` or `(b && d)` be true, then the outer `if` will always evaluate to true, so it can be dropped.  Instead, you could write this:

```
if (a && c) {...}
else if (b && d) {...}
else if ((a && d) || (b && c)) {...}     // your original 'inner' else
else {...}                               // your original 'outer' else
```

Comment: The version in the OP seems more efficient to me. What if `c` and `d` evaluate to `false`? In the original form the entire block is discarded in that case after the first evaluation, whereas here there are several `else` statements to be checked...

Comment: @RHertel You might be write on efficiency, but in terms of clarity I prefer the answer I have given.

Comment: @RHertel Don't guess about performance and compiler optimization. The stuff above is fast enough until proven otherwise.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Fair enough. I understand the compiler will optimize things anyway. But for the same reason that I mentioned, which may not be important for efficiency, I also find that the original version is clearer, as it describes from the very beginning which combinations of `true` are of interest for the evaluation of the block.

Comment: @RHertel, despite of what seems to you, think that the compiler will optimize it and (and for boolean expressions like these it can easily evaluate all the possibilities) will select the most efficient way to compile it.  Probably, being actually equivalents, both will result in the same compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial answer: You can store the expressions in bool variables before the if statements.

If the expressions do not involve function calls (and thus it is clear that they may not change in between the statements), I would expect the compiler to optimise it like this anyway.